# Access ng-repeat $first property in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with two input box, using ng-repeat i have iterated through the values,

```
<tr ng-repeat = "row in allRows" >
<td>

<input type="text" ng-model="row.name" ng-readonly="toogleRN && $first"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="number" ng-model="row.age" ng-readonly="toogleRN && $first"/>
 </td>
 <td>
  <a role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default "
                         data-ng-click="toogleIt()" data-ng-show="$first"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Edit</span>
                      </a>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

and my controller following is my controller

```
var app =  angular.module("TableDemo",[]);
app.controller('TableController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.toogleRN=true;

    $scope.toogleIt= function()
    {
        $scope.toogleRN = !$scope.toogleRN;
        console.log($scope.toogleRN);
    };

    $scope.allRows=[{name:'Name_1',age:25},
                    {name:'Name_2',age:28},
                    {name:'Name_3',age:17},
                    {name:'Name_4',age:25},
                    {name:'Name_5',age:26}];
}]);
```

the requirement first row should be read-only by-default, when click on "Edit" button it should be editable. By using above code it is full fill my requirement, but my question how can i move the `ng-readonly="toogleRN && $first"` to controller ?

Answer (score 1):

use a function :

```
ng-readonly="myFunction(toogleRN, $first, row.editable)"
// on the button 
 ng-click = row.editable = true
 // in the javascript
 $scope.myFunction = function(toogleRN, isFirt, isEditable){

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need the index number of the row basically.  You already have the data in the controller.

So you can do this,

```
ng-readonly="toogleRN && $index == 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function

```
ng-readonly="isReadable($index);"

$scope.isReadable = function($index){
    return (!$index && $scope.toogleRN)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat = "row in allRows" >
        <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="row.name" ng-readonly="isReadonly($index)"/>
        </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="row.age" ng-readonly="isReadonly($index)"/>
    </td>
     <td>
         <a role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default "
                     data-ng-click="toogleIt()" data-ng-show="$first"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Edit</span>
         </a>
     </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.toogleRN=true;
$scope.isReadonly = function(index) {
    return index == 0 && $scope.toogleRN
}
$scope.toogleIt= function()
{
    $scope.toogleRN = !$scope.toogleRN;
    console.log($scope.toogleRN);
};

$scope.allRows=[{name:'Name_1',age:25},
                {name:'Name_2',age:28},
                {name:'Name_3',age:17},
                {name:'Name_4',age:25},
                {name:'Name_5',age:26}];
```